# Write down the Equivalence classes

Tags: relations

Let $V = \{0,1,2\} \times \{0,1,2,3\}.$ We define an equivalence relation $R$ on $V$ by saying that $(a,b)R(c,d)$ if and only if $2a-b = 2c-d$. Write down the equivalence classes for $R.$

I do not get how to write the equivalence classes. The way I did it was:

$$V = \{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)\}$$

$[(0,0)] = \{(1,2)\}$, Because $2(0)-(0) = 2(1)-2$

$[(0,1)] = \{(1,3)\}$

$[(1,1)] = \{(2,3)\}$

I'm just very confused about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
(a,b) & \mapsto & 2a-b \\
\hline
(0,0) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}0 \\
(0,1) & \mapsto & -1 \\
(0,2) & \mapsto & -2 \\
(0,3) & \mapsto & -3 \\
(1,0) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}2 \\
(1,1) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}1 \\
(1,2) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}0 \\
(1,3) & \mapsto & -1 \\
(2,0) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}4 \\
(2,1) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}3 \\
(2,2) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}2 \\
(2,3) & \mapsto & \phantom{+}1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
To each number in the righthand column above corresponds one equivalence class:
$$
\begin{align}
& \{(0,3)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(0,2)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(1,3),\,(0,1)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(0,0),\,(1,2)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(1,1),\,(2,3)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(1,0),\,(2,2)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(2,1)\} \\[5pt]
& \{(2,0)\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So $\{(0,3)\},\{(0,2)\}$......are all the equivalence classes of R?

Comment: Yes. In this case each equivalence class has either one member or two.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalence classes are such that:

> Every element is in exactly one equivalence classes.  The equivalence classes together will contain every element but the classes will be disjoint.  All the elements in a class will be related to each other and not be related to any element not in the class.

I *won't* do this excercise but suppose you had a set $W = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and and an equivalence relation $S$ and you had the following relations:

$aRa, aRc,aRd$
$bRb, bRf$
$cRa,cRc, cRd$
$dRa, dRc, dRd$
$eRe$
$fRb,fRf$

Then the elements $a,c, d$ are all related to each other but none are related to any other so

1: $\{a,c,d\}$ is one equivalence class.

$b,f$ are related to each other but not to any other elements so

2: $\{b,f\}$ is another

and $e$ is related to itself but not to any other so

3: $\{e\}$ is the third equivalence class.

Now do that for $V = \{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)\}$.

Find out which pairs are related to which pairs and put them into the proper sets.

....

You might ask:  We had $aRa$ and $aRc$ and $aRd$ so we have to have $a,c,d$ is the same equivalence class, but who did we know we would have $cRd$? We if we had $a$ related to $c$ and $d$ but $c$ and $d$ not related to each other?

Well, this is an *equivalence* relation.  It is transitive and it is symmetric (as well as reflexive).  That means if we have $aRc$ and $aRd$ we must also have $cRa$ and $cRd$.  It's *because* and only because the relation is equivalence that we can divide the elements into these sets of "who is related to who" so neatly and completely.

> Equivalence classes in a *succinct* nutshell:  A collection of equivalence classes is a collection of sets of all the elements that are related to each other.

Comment: oh ok, I think I get it. So the answer should be like this?

$[(0,0)] = \{(0,0),(1,2)\}$

$[(0,1)] = \{(0,1),(1,3)\}$

and I keep going and not repeating the same pairs of ordered sets?

Comment: Yep... pretty much.   All the pairs in each class will be related to each other.  Equivalence classes are just grouping all the elements so that those related to each other are all in the same class.

Comment: ohhh, alright, I get it now. Thank you so much for the explanation.